# Google Auth call back inside custom element

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, custom-element

I'm trying to put google auth into a custom element using the code below. Its rendering correctly, and the button causes the regular google auth popup to fire, but after completing sign in, the callback is not triggered - none of the logs are triggered, and there is no error message. Any suggestions?

My guess is it has something to with the fact that I am using a class, as I read somewhere that the string needs to refer to a global function. But that's not possible in this context of course

```
customElements.define(
    "google-auth",
    class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this._profile = {};
        }

        onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
            console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
            console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
            this._profile = profile;
        };

        connectedCallback() {
            console.log("google-auth");

            this.innerHTML = `
            <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
        `;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Did you try to define window.onSignIn = this.onSignIn on the connectedCallback method?

Comment: and  `window.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this);` is even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also define the success callback explicitely as explained in the Google Auth documentation on [custom Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button).

For example:

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log("google-auth");

    this.innerHTML = `
        <div id="my-signin2"></div>
    `;

    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess' : this.onSignIn.bind(this)
    });
}
```

If you do that, the Google library must be already loaded (that is: with no `async defer` attributes) when the `connectedCallback()` is called.

If you want to keep the `async defer` attributes, you'll have to use a global `render()` function that will call a custom element method to render the button:

```
function render() { 
    GA.render() // where GA is the custom element id
}

class extends HTMLElement {
   render() {
       gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', 
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had found this too, but reverted to your solution in the comments when you provided that. In any event I'm grateful